# Problema na acentuação no JAVA

Tags: java, netbeans, acentuação

Olá,

estou com um problema na acentuação final do meu código em JAVA, segue link para visualizar melhor o problema : https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPqiZ.png

Obg.: Estou usando o NetBeans IDE 15.

Desde já, agradeço quem puder ajudar! :)

Answer (score 0):

Olá, tenta abrir as configurações da sua IDE e adiconar o parâmetro `-J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` na opção `netbeans_default_options`, geralmente essa opção fica no path `"diretorioNetbeans"/etc/netbeans.conf`

Comment: Não consegui achar essa opção "diretorioNetbeans"/etc/netbeans.conf e nem a netbeans_default_options

Comment: o "diretorioNetBeans" é o caminho onde seu netbeans está instalado, geralmente é em C://ProgramFIle, e ai dentro da pasta **etc** você vai encontrar

Comment: seria aqui https://prnt.sc/AUx5Z9Vuubmu ?

Comment: Isso mesmo meu patrão

Comment: coloquei https://prnt.sc/jErbNqUTHUob, mas, quando executo o código, as palavras acentuadas ainda aparecem com caracteres diferentes. Obrigado pela ajuda!